# Paging in gridview..in webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am paging my grid view datas. Now am on 3rd page of `gridview`.

In  3rd page I have list of buttons in each rows.

When I click on one button it goes to another webpage. Where I edit datas and save.

When I click on save it comes back to page having grid. Which loads from 1st page of grid...i want to load the 3rd page of `gridview` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted share the right code I used:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        if (Session["PageIndex"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["PageIndex"].ToString()))
            GridView1.PageIndex = (int) Session["PageIndex"];
    }

}

protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging1(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e) {
    Session["PageIndex"] = e.NewPageIndex;
}
```

Comment: it is your algorithm for paging after postpack. But my post was answer to this question

Answer (score 5):

Lets start. You can look to this [link](http://programming.top54u.com/post/ASP-Net-2-0-Gridview-Paging-using-C-sharp.aspx). Here you can see that on PageIndexChanging event 
you can get current page index with e.NewPageIndex property.

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
  GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
  //save e.NewPageIndex; property to cookie;
  bindGridView();
}
```

And you can save it in cookie after coming back you can read cookie and

```
protected void LastSession()
{
   //read last pageindex from cookie
   //set GridView1.PageIndex=<yourCookie>.Value; 
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to use cookies,  you could have the page number as query parameter to both pages, e.g. `www.example.com/mypage.aspx?Page=3`. On the Gridview page, if the parameter is present, start displaying at the specified page. If it is missing, start at Page 1.  On the edit page, use the Page number to construct the url that returns to the Gridview page, with the desired page number as a parameter.

Comment: yes you can save it anywhere you want in cookie, in querystring, in session, in DB(but not good idea) :-)

Comment: when i click on 2page in grid ...e.NewPageIndex am getting index as 1 not 2

Comment: protected void LastSession()
        {
            Int32 i = Int32.Parse(Session["page"].ToString());
            GridView1.PageIndex = i;
        }


        protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanged(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

            Session["page"] = GridView1.PageIndex;
        }

Comment: http://programming.top54u.com/post/ASP-Net-2-0-Gridview-Paging-using-C-sharp.aspx here is working sample